# Unable to set input value to blank after cloning

Tags: jquery

I am stuck. Below script works fine in cloning the whole div tab with multiple input attributes, but the issue is I am not able to reset/ or set the value to blank or null. Please help.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var inputs = 1;

        $('#btnAdd').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("asfter priovent defaulg");

            $('.btnDel:disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
            var c = $('.clonedInput:last').clone(true);

            $.each(c.find(':input'), function (i, val) {
                    var suffix = $(this).attr('name').match(/\d+/);
                    var oldN = $(this).attr('name');

                    var newN = oldN.replace('[' + suffix + ']', '[' + (parseInt(suffix) + 1) + ']');

                    $(this).attr('name', newN);    
                    $(this).find('input').val('').end();

                    c.children(':text').attr('name', newN);
                    c.children(':text').attr('name', newN).val('').end();
            });
            $('.clonedInput:last').after(c);
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>

<form id="myForm">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="clonedInput">
            <input type="button" name="btnDelete[1]" class="btnDel" value="Delete" disabled="disabled" /> 
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>First</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <input type="text" name="firstname[1]" size="10">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Second</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <input type="text" name="LastName[1]" size="10">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Third</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <input type="text" name="Status[1]" size="10">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="add another name" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you do `e.preventDefault()` right at the beginning of your click event?

Comment: I was just trying different options, with or without that piece of code it does not allow me to reset the values.

Comment: Aah okay, yeah it's probably not needed.  So which part of your code are you using to reset the text in an input field? and which input field? Are you trying to use the code `c.children(':text').attr('name', newN).val('').end();` to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to `.find()` an input when you're already iterating through the inputs.

Change:

```
$(this).find('input').val('').end();
```

to

`$(this).val('').end();` or `this.value = '';`

Comment: Hi one more follow up question. When I submit the form without dynamically adding input attributes, the form works as expected. But once I click on "Add another  name" button it adds the new div tags with input attributes. But when I submit the form it is trying to reload the page. Do you know what I can do to avoid this action.

Comment: if you're using jquery you need to look at the `.submit()` method: https://api.jquery.com/submit/